# How to use Sylvester's law of inertia to show positive definiteness

Tags: linear-algebra

Let

$G = (<e_i,e_j>)_{i,j=1,...3} :=\left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -1 \end{matrix} \right)$

be a symmetric bilinear form $< \cdot, \cdot>$ with regard to the canonical basis of $\mathbb R^3$,

$H:= \left\{ x \in \mathbb R^3 | <x,x> = -1 \right\}$

and for $a \in H$ name the orthogonal complement of $\mathbb Ra$ with regard to the upper bilinear form: $T_aH$.

I need to show that the restriction $< \cdot, \cdot>|_{T_aH \times T_aH}$ is positiv definite with the help of Sylvester's law of inertia.

How can I do this? I know that we have $\mathbb R^3 = V = V_0 \oplus V_+ \oplus V_-$ and in this case $V_0 = 0$, $V_+= <\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}>$ and $V_-= <\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}>$ as these are the eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalues 1 and -1. 
But that's not the orthogonal complement or $H$, so how can I use this? (Besides I do not really know how to compute the orthogonal complement in this case. If that's necessary, I would be pleased if someone gave me a hint.)

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

By Sylvester's law, you know that $\Bbb Ra$ Is a maximal negative definite subspace. If $\langle b,b \rangle<0$ For some $yb$ in the orthogonal complement to $a$, check to see how the metric would behave in the subspace generated by $a$ and $b$.

With a little more argument, conclude the restriction of the metric to the complement is positive definite.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'll try;) But just one question - what do you mean by "maximal negative definite"?

Comment: I mean it is a negative definite subspace which is not *properly* contained in any other negative definite subspace. This is what Sylvester's law is about :)

Comment: That's what I thought, too, but $\mathbb Ra$, as it's not <(0,0,1)>, is not the negative definite part of the Sylvester decomposition, so I'm a bit confused how to use that.

Comment: @xxx But Sylvester's law says *all* maximal negative definite subspaces have equal dimension.  It also says the same thing for positive definite subspaces and for isotropic subspaces. If a Sylvester decomposition means decomposing the space into an orthogonal sum of definite and isotropic components, then you should be aware that this isn't unique, ie there is no "the" decomposition.

Comment: @xxx so $\Bbb R a \oplus (\Bbb R a)^\perp$ is another Sylvester decomposition.